# Converting HTML functions into PHP scripts. (two select values to multiply)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My job is to convert the following javascript functions into PHP and display the correct results. How do you use PHP to multiply the two values of the NumA and NumB select options? The discount must be displayed in the discount input box, as well as the grand total in the total input box. I am having difficulties creating a PHP script that takes the two selected options's values and multiplies them, while displaying the two results in the boxes below.

This is the HTML code with the functions that I need to convert to PHP.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
<script>
var numA = 0;
function totalA(valA) {
if (valA) {
    numA = Number(valA);}
var disc = numB*numA;
var totalCost = (numA - disc); 
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("discount").value = "$" + disc.toFixed(2);}
var numB = 0;
function totalB(valB) {
if (valB) {
    numB = Number(valB);}
var disc =  numB*numA;
var totalCost = (numA - disc);
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalCost.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("discount").value = "$" + disc.toFixed(2);}   
</script>    

</head>
<div align="center">
<br>
<form name id="Main">
<select id="numA" placeholder="Please select a service" onchange="totalA(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your service</option>
    <option value="125">Makeover</option>
    <option value="60">Hair Styling</option>
    <option value="35">Manicure</option>
    <option value="200">Permanent Makeup</option>   
</select>
<br><br>
<select id="NumB" placeholder="Please select the discount" onchange="totalB(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the discount</option>
    <option value="0">0%</option>
    <option value=".1">10%</option>
    <option value=".2">20%</option>  
    </select>
    <br><br>
<td>Discount Coupon: <input id="discount" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly/></td>
<td>Grand Total: <input id="total" name="showTotal" type="text" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly=""/></td>
<br><br>
</form>
<hr>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: What PHP have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 I've tried indexing both variables and multiplying them together using a $result variable. I am unsure how to get the result to display correctly.

Comment: (javascript) **1** Collect the form's data using a `FormData` object. **2** Submit the formdata to a php file, using AJAX. (php) **3** Retrieve vars passed to php and perform calculations with them. **4** Print result. (javascript) **5** Get responseText of ajax call (if succeeded) **6** copy retrieved text to correct output element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update your form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="service" id="service" placeholder="Please select a service">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your service</option>
        <option value="125">Makeover</option>
        <option value="60">Hair Styling</option>
        <option value="35">Manicure</option>
        <option value="200">Permanent Makeup</option>   
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select name="discount" id="discount" placeholder="Please select the discount">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select the discount</option>
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value=".1">10%</option>
        <option value=".2">20%</option>  
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Process the form submission with PHP (Calculate total cost & discount):

```
<?php
    $service = isset($_POST['service']) ? $_POST['service'] : 0;
    $discount = isset($_POST['discount']) ? $_POST['discount'] : 0;
    $total_discount = number_format($discount * $service, 2);
    $total_cost = number_format($service - $total_discount, 2);
?>
```

Finally, display the total cost & discount:

```
<p>Discount Coupon: <input id="discount" type="text" value="&dollar;<?php echo $total_discount; ?>"/></p>
<p>Grand Total: <input id="total" type="text" value="&dollar;<?php echo $total_cost; ?>"/></p>
```

Comment: did you get it to work with this solution?

Comment: Yes, the full code is here: http://pastebin.com/kwv7exSG